# Sending values from parent to an input box loaded on the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

hi everyone pls i need assistance on this one. The script is meant to send the name variable to an input box in another document to be loaded on the iframe both the iframe tag and this script are in the document but the file to be loaded to the iframe commes from another document. I only need to know how to send that var name to the iframe when the iframe is loaded.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
            $('.men').click(function(){
               var name = $(this).attr('href');
              $('#frame').contents().find('#url').val(name);
            });
         });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you control the code that's executed inside the iframe, or do you control only the parent?

Comment: i can control both

Answer (score 0):

In your child frame, define a simple function:

```
<script>
function updateUrl(name) {
   $('#url').val(name);
}
</script>
```

In your parent, call this function

```
<script>
$(function(){
            $('.men').click(function(){
               var name = $(this).attr('href');
               document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.updateUrl(name);

            });
         });

</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).contentWindow.updateUrl is not a function that's the error i get

Comment: Sad mix of jquery and native script :s

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).contentWindow.updateUrl is not a function that's the error i get

Comment: <script>
function updateUrl(name) {
   $('#url').val(name);
}
</script>  i put the script in the file loaded on the iframe  while the later is in the file where the iframe is set